# objective-c small class overhead

Tags: objective-c, pointers, performance, abstract-data-type

I was writing a class file and I included a `CGPoint` as an Ivar.  This got me wondering about the overhead associated with smaller objective-c data structures.  Is the memory footprint of something like a `CGPoint` significant enough to justify making a pointer to it, or would I just be making a pointer to 2 `CGfloat` values?  For that matter, if all I need are x/y coordinates why not just stick 2 ints in as ivars?

On a related note, is there a nomenclature for describing tiny data structures, like "petty data structures", or "trivial data structures"; a word that describes a a struct made of a few primitives.

Comment: CGPoint is a structure with two floats. I don't understand what your are telling about a pointer. You never need to use pointer to CGPoint but for passing as reference to any function or method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certainly issues with small objects, but there are supposedly several small-object optimizations in the system already.

In general, if you need an object, use an object.  If not, then don't.

However, the bigger issue is to write your code so that it is easy to read by humans, and easy to maintain by humans.  Use performance tools (like Instruments) to isolate places where system resource utilization needs to be addressed, and **only then** address those issues.

Of course, there are obvious *stupid* things to avoid, but in general, focus on a clean design, and easy to read/change implementation.  Running the performance tools on your test suite should easily spot anything too wrong.

Comment: Awesome, that answers my question nicely.  Any idea about small data structure nomenclature?  If there's noting set in stone then I'm going to coin the phrase "petty data structure" as a data structure that holds 4 or fewer primitives and has only constructors, deconstructors, setters, and getters as member functions.

Comment: "Small object" is the term typically used for, well, objects that are "small" (for some definition of small).  An object in C++ that is composed of simple types has a more formal definition, and is known as POD (plain old data), but that monicker has grown legs and made it into standardeze.  For the objects you are talking about, I would just use "small objects" and most people should know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

First don't worry about the overhead until you have a performance issue.

Most (but not all) object-oriented languages make a distinct between small, non-object, types and larger, object-based, ones; but the boundary is fuzzy. A useful distinction to decide how to represent a type is whether you think of it as a simple *value*, which you probably think as *operated on* or *calculated with*; or something more involved, which may be something which has inherent *behaviour*, *operates on* etc.

The built-in primitive types are mostly values: integers, characters, etc. In that vein complex numbers, fractions, coordinates etc. are simple values - use structures; trees, stacks, hierarchies are not - use objects.

On your related note consider many use "value", you can also consider ["composite"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_data_type). "Petty" isn't a good choice, wrong connotations ;-) Others might say "basic", "trivial", "structure" or "record" - while the latter two can also be used to refer to very large types they often are used for small ones.